# Android ExpandableListView onClickListener for Group row

Tags: android

Tab1 is a expandablelistview and the Tab2 is a view. Default selected tab is Tab1. When I click on a group row, a webview pops up.

When I select Tab2 and again Tab1, group row web view doesn't open on a first click. It opens on 2nd click. so what happening ? I am confused...

Comment: is something has to do with focus ?

Answer (score 0):

First touch on a view gets focus.  Second is click.  You can get around this by setting the view unfocusable.  Then the first touch will register as a click.